# Displaying all columns in SQL and also sum of columns with same ID in the last Repeating row

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables

**OrderDetails**:

```
Id          Name       type      Quantity  
------------------------------------------
2009        john       a         10        
2009        john       a         20        
2010        sam        b         25            
2011        sam        c         50       
2012        sam        d         30
```

**ValueDetails**:

```
Id          Value
-------------------
2009        300
2010        500
2011        200
2012        100
```

I need to get an output which displays the data as such :

```
Id          Name       type      Quantity  Price
-------------------------------------------------
2009        john       a         10        
2009        john       a         20        9000
2010        sam        b         25            
2011        sam        c         50       
2012        sam        d         30        25500
```

The price is calculated by Value x Quantity and the sum of the values is displayed in the last repeating row of the given Name.

I tired to use sum and group by but I get only two rows. I need to display all 5 rows. How can I write this query?

Comment: What have **you tried** so far??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Row_Number with max of Row_Number to get this formatted sum

```
;with cte as (
select od.*, sm= sum( od.Quantity*vd.value ) over (partition by Name),
    RowN = row_number() over(partition by Name order by od.id)
    from #yourOrderDetails od 
    inner join #yourValueDetails vd
        on od.Id = vd.Id
        )
    select Id, Name, Type, Quantity, 
        case when max(RowN) over(partition by Name) = row_number() over(partition by Name order by Id) 
        then sm else null end as ActualSum 
        from cte
```

Your input tables:

```
create table #yourOrderDetails (Id int, Name varchar(20), type varchar(2), Quantity int)
insert into #yourOrderDetails (Id, Name, type, Quantity) values
 (2009  ,'john','a',  10 )       
,(2009  ,'john','a',  20 )      ,(2010  ,'sam ','b',  25 )        
,(2011  ,'sam ','c',  50 )      ,(2012  ,'sam ','d',  30 )  

create table #yourValueDetails(Id int, Value Int)
insert into #yourValueDetails(Id, value) values 
 (  2009    ,    300   )    ,(  2010    ,    500   )
,(  2011    ,    200   )    ,(  2012    ,    100   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    a.ID,
          a.Name,
          a.Type,
          a.quantity,
          price = (a.quantity * b.price)
FROM      OrderDetails a LEFT JOIN
          ValueDetails b on a.id = b.id
```

This will put the price on every row. If you want to do a SUM by Id,Name and Type it's not going to show the individual records like you show them above. If you want to put a SUM on one of the lines that share the same Id, Name and Type then you'd need a rule to figure out which one and then you could probably use a CASE statement to decide on which line you want to show the SUM total.